# MDX Query Tuple representation using ampersand

Tags: mdx

What is the difference between representing tuple in an mdx query as

```
[CF Type].[CF TYPE].&[6]
```

**OR**

```
 [ValScen].[Scenario Type].&[Term Point Rates]
```

Can I use the &[number] and the &[actual string] format interchangeably? If the cube is generated by another system, can the &[6] be different for each generation in usual practice? Or is it safer to use StrToMember or StrToSet. But this is not efficient as per [this](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966527.aspx) article. To give some context, in my case I use it like in below pseudocode

```
SELECT NON EMPTY { [Measures].x}    ON COLUMNS, NON EMPTY { (My Column1 * My Column2)}   DIMENSION PROPERTIES MEMBER_CAPTION ON ROWS FROM    ( SELECT ( { [CF Type].[CF TYPE].&[6] } ) ON COLUMNS FROM 
     (   SELECT ( { [ValScen].[Scenario Type].&[Term Point Rates] } ) ON COLUMNS FROM [My Cube]]))   
       WHERE ( [ValScen].[Scenario Type].&[Term Point Rates], [CF Type].[CF TYPE].&[6] )
```

Answer (score 1):

Those are members and not tuples. A Tuple would be surrounded by braces ().

I think they are interchangeable syntax if you’re using the caption such as .&[hello] and .[hello] but if you use the key then the ampersand is mandatory.